# how to remove and change qgsvertexmarker in QGIS using c++ code?

Tags: qgis, c++

In QGIS following code is used to set marker at point A.

```
  QgsVertexMarker * marker = new QgsVertexMarker(mPlugin->iface()->mapCanvas());
  marker->setColor(Qt::black);
  marker->setIconType(2);
  marker->setCenter(A);
```

How to delete this marker using C++ code?

In python it is

```
 canvas.scene().removeItem(marker)
```

I am using this marker in a loop where point A will change continuously so i would like to delete marker at previous position and insert in new.

when i use below code marker is deleted permanently.

```
  mPlugin->iface()->mapCanvas()->scene()->removeItem(marker);
```

so how to use this marker to plot moving point?

Comment: and the very same code does not work in C++? The only difference is, that you have to delete it from the memory as well with `delete marker;` after removing it from the canvas

Comment: how to do that? I did some little change and tried to do so. but it is not getting removed.

Comment: `mPlugin->iface()->mapCanvas()->scene()->removeItem( marker ); delete marker;` See [QGraphicsScene](https://qt-project.org/doc/qt-4.8/qgraphicsscene.html#removeItem)

Comment: @MatthiasKuhn  thank you it works. please see my edit

Comment: If you change the question like this, please also update the title. You will have to call `marker->setCenter( A );` repeatedly without removing the marker.

Comment: i have changed title. if it is not good please suggest some other. Thank You.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

## Removing

The marker is a QGraphicsItem which is placed on a QGraphicsScene (mapCanvas). To remove it, you have to do:

```
mPlugin->iface()->mapCanvas()->scene()->removeItem( marker );
delete marker;
```

In C++ in contrast to python you have to take care of memory. So everything acquired by `new` will later have to be deleted with `delete`.
In the case of Qt (which is the library QGIS is using) it sometimes deletes objects for you. Sometimes means, when Qt takes ownership of an object, which normally happens, when you specify a parent. In this case it will exist as long as the parent exists. In this case in the line `new QgsVertexMarker(mPlugin->iface()->mapCanvas());` you specify the mapCanvas as parent. But, because you use [QGraphicsScene::removeItem](https://qt-project.org/doc/qt-4.8/qgraphicsscene.html#removeItem) you get the ownership back and have to delete it manually again.

## Moving

You can also move a marker. You don't need to remove and re-add it, you can simply call the method `QVertexMarker::setCenter` with new coordinates and you are done.

```
marker->setCenter( QgsPoint( 100, 200 ) );
```

Comment: For removing the code you told is good so i accept your answer. but for moving old point is not getting deleted. when point is changed it shows old and new point. is there any way to show only current point and remove old points.

Comment: This works here (tested with python, but this should not matter). Which version of QGIS are you using? Can you try to pan to another area and back after moving the cursor and check if it is still there? It seems to me it's an artifact.

Comment: I am using QGIS 1.8